# Can't Upload File throught Rails Docker, Carrierwave to AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, carrierwave

I have an apps in RAILS running under Docker which I want it to upload document on a S3 Bucket using the Gem Carrierwave

When I uploaded the file everything seems fine but the file never appear in my bucket.

Am I missing something?  Maybe a Permission or a Open Port?

My configs are as fellow:

aws.rb

```
require 'aws-sdk'

Aws.config.update({
  region: ENV['aws_region'],
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['aws_access_key_id'],ENV['aws_secret_access_key'])
})
```

carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage      = :aws
  config.aws_bucket   = ENV['aws_bucket']
  config.aws_acl      = 'public-read'


  config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
  config.aws_attributes = {
    expires: 1.week.from_now.httpdate,
    cache_control: 'max-age=604800'
  }

  config.aws_credentials = {
    :region             => ENV['aws_region'],
    :force_path_style   => true,
    :signature_version  => 'v4',
    :credentials        => Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['aws_access_key_id'],ENV['aws_secret_access_key']),
  }

end
```

docker-compose.yml

```
appsnginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    volumes:
      - ./log:/apps/log
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
      - "8443:443"
    depends_on:
      - apps
apps:
    build: .
    command: puma -C config/puma.rb
    volumes:
        - .:/apps
        - ./tmp/uploads-cache:/apps/tmp/uploads
    expose:
        - "3000"
```

document_uploader.rb

```
class DocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :aws

  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.env}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}"
  end

  def default_url
    "https://placehold.it/1920X1280"
  end


  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads-cache"
  end


  def extension_whitelist
    %w(pdf doc htm html docx txt jpg jpeg png)
  end

  def filename
    "#{File.basename(file.filename,".*")}__#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  protected
  def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:
I assured myself that the "`cache_dir`" folder was accessible and setup as a shared volume between my system and my docker
I assured myself that my AWS Bucket folders was create and accessible from the public

The problem seems to come from the "`secure_token`" AND "`filename`" methods of my "`DocumentUploader`"

I had to change this

```
"#{File.basename(file.filename,".*")}__#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
```

by

```
"#{File.basename(original_filename,".*")}__#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
```

The error msg was

> can't modify frozen NilClass model.instance_variable_get(var) or
>   model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)

I had a Hard Time finding it cause it was basically silent. It didn't show up in any logs, output or screen.  I stubble on it when I put traces everywhere ;)